# Manually indent needed again when HTML tag is closed in VS Code

Tags: html, tags, visual-studio-code, newline, indentation

In Microsoft VS Code when I'm closing HTML tag (e.g.  on bottom image), current position will be moved to the first column and remove tabs indent. Then I need to indent manually with tabs again. How can I fix it?

[image: GIF Example - please click here…]

My settings.json file:

```
...
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.wrappingIndent": "none",
"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"html.format.endWithNewline": false,
...
```

Comment: `"editor.detectIndentation": false,` is your issue. Make that `true`

Comment: I know i'm asking for a slap, but am i the only one annoyed by the fact that disabling the _detection_ of indentation messes up the indentation itself, and the solution is not to fix the bug, but to revert to an annoying setting? 5 years later, the same bug is there!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I set the options in `settings.json` to:

```
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "editor.autoIndent": false
```

And it's working now. Fixed.

Comment: The "editor.autoIndent" list of options that showed up for me didn't have false, but I chose "keep" and it seems to work.

Comment: For me, setting editor autoindent to advanced instead of full solved the problem while keeping all features of indentation as they are.

Answer (score 2):

In your `settings.json`, `"editor.detectIndentation": false`, is your issue. Make that `true`.

*i.e.*

```
...
"editor.detectIndentation": true,
"editor.wrappingIndent": "none",
"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"html.format.endWithNewline": false,
...
```